# How do you create a Spring MVC project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to follow the basic tutorial for Spring MVC but got lost at creating a new project in Eclipse.
It seems to me that most tutorials assume you know how to create a Spring Project in Eclipse.
Any advice on where to get started or tutorials which explain how to set up Eclipse would be appreciated.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You want to create a "Dynamic Web Project".  Follow the steps here:  [Spring MVC Tutorial with Eclipse and Tomcat](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/02/08/spring-mvc-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-tomcat.html).

Also, here is the Eclipse documentation for Dynamic Web Projects:  http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/ccwebprj.html

Comment: First link is dead.

Comment: ... and gets detected by malwarebytes as a trojan

Answer (score 14):

Download Spring STS (SpringSource Tool Suite) and choose Spring Template Project from the Dashboard. This is the easiest way to get a preconfigured spring mvc project, ready to go.

Answer (score 11):

You don't necessarily have to create a *Spring project*.  Almost all Java web applications have he same project structure.  In almost every project I create, I automatically add these source folder:

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/test/java
- src/test/resources
- src/main/webapp*

src/main/webapp isn't actually a source folder.  The web.xml file under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF will allow you to run your java application on any Java enabled web server (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.).  I typically add the [Jetty Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135289/how-do-you-create-a-spring-mvc-project-in-eclipse) to my POM (assuming you use Maven), and launch the web app in development using **mvn clean jetty:run**.

Comment: I agree. Don't create a "Spring Project", and don't use SpringIDE. If you really want to learn Spring, create a dynamic web project, and then start loading in JARs, configs, etc., and learn Spring MVC from the ground up.

Answer (score 10):

This is the easiest way :

**step 1) install Spring Tool Suite (STS)** for eclipse (version 3.7.0RELEASE or above)
To do this you can go to Help >> eclipse market place , then type Spring Tool suite in search box.

**step 2)  now go to file >> new  >>  spring project** as shown in the image below
[image]

**step 3)now choose the template as "spring MVC Project"** and give a name to your project on the top as shown below ( I named it 'SpringProject')
[image]

**step 4)now give a base package name like this**
[image]

and that is . The project will be created in a few minutes and Now you can right click on it and run on server.

Answer (score 0):

1. **step 1**: create a new "Dynamic Web Project" in eclipse.
2. **step 2**: right click on the created project.
3. **step 3**: click on "configure" option.
4. **step 4**: click on "convert to maven project".

here is more detailed information ->  [1]: https://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/