# Maven project for Spring MVC Deploying in GlassFish Error(s)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, glassfish-4

I have a Spring MVC web app created with Maven project. I try to deploy/run it in GlassFish, and I receive the following error(s).

The error(s) below:

> cannot Deploy springMvcJdbcTemplate
>   deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: 
>   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. Please see server.log for more details.

Below is what I have in 'pom.xml' file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this is what I have in 'MvcConfiguration.java' file (I use 'spring-mvc-achetype' for this Maven project):

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://7d0\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;databaseName=db_name");
    dataSource.setUsername("usrnm");
    dataSource.setPassword("pwd");

    return dataSource;
}
```

I have added 'sqljdbc4.jar' file in 'C:\Users\7d0.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\sqljdbc4\4.0\', but I still receive the same error(s).

How should I fix the error(s)? Thanks is advance.

Comment: from that much of error log, all I can say is some jar is missing.

Comment: @user3320018 - thanks for commenting. Do you know how to add 'sqlserver4.jar' file to Maven Spring MVC using 'spring-mvc-achetype' project?

Comment: Using eclipse...Yes. you will need to use the wizard and give the local path for repository for your jars, once set, your project will refer to all required jars from there. You will need to include the dependency for sqlserver4.jar in your pom.xml.

Comment: That's fine too...but then you need to make sure that you have contextConfigLocation configured in your web.xml.

Comment: @user3320018 - I don't know how to do that in Eclipse. Can you show me how?

Comment: here are few of the best ways. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135289/how-do-you-create-a-spring-mvc-project-in-eclipse

Comment: @user3320018 - It is for Spring MVC created using 'Dynamic Web Project', not with Maven 'spring-mvc-achetype' project that I am working on. Any other idea?

Comment: Here is what you need: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place the sqlserver jar file in the lib dir of the glassfish server

Comment: Thanks for your help. I make a change for the above dependency, and I receive the error icon in the left of that dependency. The error is 'Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0'

Comment: I place sqlserver4.jar file in 'lib' folder of Glassfish server & setup a JDBC connection in Glassfish, but I still have the error. Any idea?

Comment: when a server starts up, it adds some jars to  classpath. This jar needs to be in that classpath. So, check how the `java` process for that server is getting executed. It may not be adding the sql server jar to its classpath

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your WAR file to see that it is being packaged along with the other jar files?  The other thing you can do is add the JDBC jar into the server/lib directory.

Comment: I place sqlserver4.jar file in 'lib' folder of Glassfish server & setup a JDBC connection in Glassfish, but I still have the error.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from missing library, there are other two things(basically one thing) to make sure:

> applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF folder in your project.

Secondly,

> If you are limited in including the application context as in above, then you must write configuration for the same as somewhat like in below.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/application-contexts/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Please also refer to the following for setting up Spring MVC with Maven and Eclipse.
[Link Here](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute)

Comment: I don't have applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF folder in Maven project. I use 'spring-mvc-achetype' for Spring MVC with Maven; therefore, I don't have it. I have 'web.xml' file in that folder instead.