# working flow of MvC pattern in eclipse luna IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, model-view-controller

Am a beginner of eclipse ide user. Please can any 1 help me how mvc pattern link in eclipse hierarchy with an example. Once project is created , under src/ folder create a necessary file and show me the flow of page linking from view to model and model to controller and to database using a login functionality.

I want to know where exactly what stuff to write, for example functions in one file , object and parameters in another , ids in jsp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Theresa Forster is correct, however, as someone who worked many years with Eclipse, I want to add a few things.

Eclipse has a strong eco-system of plugins that you can use (install) to your advantage. Some of these plugins seem to be what you need:

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/alveole-studio-mvc-web-project

Additionally, if you feel like using the Spring framework to help you code, this may be useful as well:

- [How do you create a Spring MVC project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135289/how-do-you-create-a-spring-mvc-project-in-eclipse)
- http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/
- http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute

Spring has a strong ecosystem and is generally regarded as the way to go with MVC apps when using Eclipse for Java. You can say that Spring is for Java as ASP.NET is for C#. Both are strong frameworks that help you with MVC.

If however, you don't want to go this way, you can always go hardcore and create the file structure yourself:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74968/how-do-you-organize-your-mvc-framework-while-supporting-modules-plugins

Hope I helped !

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you, usually you would be using a framework like Spring,

MVC is simple but some people don't think correctly about it.

V = View, this is your webpage/form/console output, There should be no logic in this code area.

C = Controller, this is your business logic, - Use Services and Managers to perform the tasks you want (UserService.getUsers(); or BasketService.getBasketForUser(UserService.getCurrentUser()); )

Now we come to M = Model.
most online tutorials refer to the model as the Database...

This is wrong. 
Let me describe a system i once worked on.

We loaded a Record or series of Records from the Database into ValueObjects. 
We then Transformed these into DataTransferObjects which we used to transfer data around the system.

The DTO (Data Transfer Object) is the Model, as it is the Data that the Business Logic works on.  and not the Database or Value Object (the system representation of the Database Records) as the Model may merge multiple Tables together to make a more useful DataModel.

As for structure you could do anything

/Services

/DAOs

/Entities

/View