# Spring Basics : Development with xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am beginner in using spring and java in regard to web development.
Though I understand concepts well but what makes me go mad is creating xml files.

Example:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebForm</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WebForm</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

If I have no example in front of me and I try to code anything from scratch in spring, do I need to remember format of these xml files. Do I need to remember these big xml namespace urls?

How do I remember mapping names and their order? How do I know I may be missing some xml context which I could have used?

Comment: Use eclipse or some other editors , they will automatically generate these files for you later you can change them according to your requirement .

Comment: use below Link for further assistance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135289/how-do-you-create-a-spring-mvc-project-in-eclipse

Comment: Why are you using such an old specification? Servlet 2.4 was released in November 2003, a lot have happened since then.

Comment: Starting with new projects in Spring? Go with [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) and forget about xml. Things will go quicker.

Comment: Even without boot, it's been a while that you can create a whole webapp without any xml. That said, why would you code without any examples and documentation in front of you. Just use examples and documentations: that's what they're for.

Comment: You do not need to remember. Have your examples  ready while developing from scratch. BTW, The sample web.xml which you have shared, follows JEE specs. Your xml simply references Spring's dispatcher servlet. Spring's documentation is not supposed to help you on web.xml.